# Flask Sqlalchemy model working in python shell but not in web interface

Tags: python-2.7, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am writing a simple web application in flask(python) which will ask students to fill experimental data in a form and that data will be submitted on a server.

My user class looks like:

```
 class User(db.Model):  
    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    email=db.Column(db.String,unique=True)  
    name=db.Column(db.String)
    password=db.Column(db.String)
    data = db.relationship('ExpData', backref='student', lazy='dynamic')
```

and ExpData class, which will store data looks like:

```
 class ExpData(db.Model):
    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    exp_1_data=db.Column(db.String)
    submission_date=db.Column(db.DateTime)
    user_id=db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

Now User model works perfectly, whide ExpData models does not put anything in database. I used the following lines to achieve it:

```
 u=models.User(email=usern,name=nameu,password=userp,rollno=rollno)
 db.session.add(u)
 db.session.commit()
```

Then in required function:

```
user=g.user
dat=models.ExpData(exp_1_data='dataStr',submit=1,submission_date=datetime.now(),student=user)
db.session.add(dat)
db.session.commit()
```

in Python shell it works perfectly. But for some reason through web interface its not working.

*Other details:*
Users are logged in via a login_user() function provided by Flask-Login
Then user is assigned to g.user through another decorator

```
@app.before_request
  def before_request():
  g.user = current_user
```

Then Database entry is done whenever following function is executed upon visiting the url

```
@app.route('/exp1echo', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def exp1echo():
    exp1_data={}
    exp1_data["ans"]=float(request.args.get("ans")) #getting some data through ajax 'get' call
    user=g.user
    filename = user.name+" simplePrint.pdf" # save file with user name in file name 
    pdf=render_template('exp1_post.html',exp1_data=exp1_data)
    pisa.CreatePDF(pdf.encode("ISO-8859-1"), file(filename, "wb"))
    pdf.close() # Just fyi this call does return an error 
     #"No handlers could be found for logger "xhtml2pdf"" but all works fine
    abc={'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
    dataStr=str(abc)
    dat=ExpData(exp_1_data='dataStr',submit=1,submission_date=datetime.now(),student=g.user)
    db.session.add(dat)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify({'base_vl':1}) # return some value to ajax call
```

User loader is defined as:

```
lm = LoginManager()
lm.init_app(app)


@lm.user_loader
  def load_user(id):
  return models.User.query.get(int(id))
```

Users are registered through following URL:

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    user_pass=request.form["password"]
    user_name=request.form["username"]
    name_=request.form["name"]
    u=models.User(email=user_name,name=name_,password=user_pass)
    db.session.add(u)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

return render_template('register_form.html')
```

Comment: Without some context around that code it's hard to say. When are these snippets executed? When is `g.user` given a value? What is "required function"?

Comment: I did that for brevity. Now i have given more details. Please let me know if i shall give any more details

Comment: What does your `@login_manager.user_loader` implementation look like?

Comment: Updated. Also I have updated another "register" function which saves the created users. It works perfectly fine. g.user call works fine too, if i use it for displaying various stored information in ExpData class (entered through python shell).
Just checked: in register() function i can get ExpData call to work with user=u assignment. If it is of any help

Comment: This won't help anything, but if `g.user` is nothing more than `current_user`, you can just use `current_user`.

Comment: How do you log users in? Do you can `login_user`? If you don't, that could be your problem.

Comment: Yes. after user supplies user name and password, it is compared to the list in data base and then login_user() function is called. Login_user() is working fine as far as i can tell. As otherwise @login_required decorator should not let me see the page right?

Comment: You ExpData model  defines 3 columns excluding the primary key, but you have given 4 arguments to models.ExpData() why?

Comment: I am sorry, during copy pasting the code i left one line it seems. submit is there in original code. Its just an integer which i am planning to use as boolean- zero/non zero value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is embarrassing! Found out the error. For some reason pdf.close() function in exp1echo() gives an error (as I mentioned earlier). That error does not show any message during debugging nor it exits the programme. Hence I ignored it. But it terminates the execution of that function. So it was not sending any call to data base. So I commented it out and voila! It worked.